# How to connect Guidewire to Oracle database?

Tags: guidewire

I have installed Oracle in my system and wanted to change my local database to Oracle, but making changes in the database-config.xml I am unable to get my server started and getting the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException : No Appropriate database found in
configuration: env = 'local'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your configuration file (database-config.xml) the parameter **env="local"**.

Example:

```
 <database
    autoupgrade="full"
    name="BillingCenterDatabase"
    dbtype="oracle"
    env="local">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, after trying that I am getting another exception , DBException: Error loading database connection

Comment: Usually in your stack trace, you should be able to find more information of why the connection is failing: it may be a wrong port, a wrong username, password etc.
The information will start with 'Caused by: '